# django smart-selects ajax configuration

Tags: python, ajax, django, django-smart-selects

So I have finally implemented smart-selects (https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects) on the admin side, but now when I try to get the actual filters to work on the user side, the filters don't work. I've tried to research a solution to this, and it seems like I need to implement ajax in order to get the smart-select filters to work properly. I'm also sure my form.py is set up incorrectly, but I cannot figure out an alternate to to calling .objects.all() because I thought smart-selects would do the proper filtering in the background.

I will include both my models.py and forms.py in case the solution lies in them. I have never worked an ajax script before and my research hasn't pointed me in any direction where to start.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedForeignKey

class Status(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=25)

    ## For the API
    def __str__(self):
        return self.status

    ## Eliminates title plurality in the admin interface
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural="Status"

class Lab(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)

    ## For the API
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    ## Eliminates title plurality in the admin interface
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural="Lab"

class Category(models.Model):
    lab = models.ForeignKey(Lab)
    name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)

    ## For the API
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    ## Eliminates title plurality in the admin interface
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural="Category"


class SubCategory(models.Model):
    lab = models.ForeignKey(Lab)
    category = ChainedForeignKey(
            Category, 
            chained_field = 'lab', 
            chained_model_field = 'lab', 
            show_all = False, 
            auto_choose = True
        )
    subcategory = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    ## For the API
    #def __str__(self):
    #   return self.category

    ## Eliminates title plurality in the admin interface
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural="SubCategory"
```

forms.py

```
import datetime
from django import forms

## importing models
from .models import Category, Lab, SubCategory  ## need these tables to     populate dropdown menus 'Category' and 'Lab'
from submit_app.models import Incident
from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedForeignKey

## importing crispy form utilities
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout, Field, Submit, Div
from crispy_forms.bootstrap import AppendedText, PrependedText, FormActions

## importing regex validator
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

## Maybe best to try to use ModelForm....it seems to have overwhelming internet support
from django.forms import ModelForm


class IncidentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Incident
        fields = [  'date_occurred', 
                    'number_of_samples_affected',
                    'capa',
                    'title',
                    'description',
                    'category',
                    'lab',
                    'subcategory',
                    'upload1',
                    'upload2',
                    'upload3'
                    ]

    ## Pre-populated dropdown menu
    lab = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Lab.objects.all(),
        label ="Lab"
    )

    ## Pre-populated dropdown menu
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Category.objects.all(),
        label = "Category"
    )

    subcategory = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=SubCategory.objects.all(),
        label = "SubCategory"
    )

    date_occurred = forms.DateField(
        label="Date Incident Occurred", 
        initial=datetime.date.today()
    )

    number_of_samples_affected = forms.IntegerField(
        label="Number of Samples Affected",
        initial='0'
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`smart selects` has it's own form field types. You are overriding that for `category` right now in your form:

```
## Pre-populated dropdown menu
category = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    queryset=Category.objects.all(),
    label = "Category"
)
```

Remove all the code above from your form. When you are using a `ChainedForeignKey`, the model field's default form field type is provided by `smart selects` (see [ChainedModelChoiceField](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects/blob/master/smart_selects/form_fields.py#L12-L35) in the source).

The Javascript that performs AJAX calls is a small inline script that is rendered as part of the form field supplied by `smart selects`.

You don't have to replace the code with anything, as the field is rendered automatically when included in a `ModelForm`.

Comment: Thanks! I took out the code for lab, category, and subcategory. But on the user side, I'm still not getting the categories/subcategories to update depending on what lab is chosen, even though I've set up the linkage on the admin side.

Comment: Open a web debugger on the page; when a lab is selected, do you see a 404 or 500 error for an Ajax function pop up? Mark sure you have added `    url(r'^chaining/', include('smart_selects.urls')),` to your base urls.py and that your template includes [JQuery>=1.10](http://code.jquery.com/) in a script tag prior to rendering any forms. If you have further issues, probably best to open a new question with any error codes, etc

Answer (score 0):

Ian Price's reaction works just fine. I have tried it and its pretty working. The issue is with the loading of jQuery library. It must be the first one on top of any tags to be loaded

Base.html

```
<head>
    <title>testing</title>
    {% load static %}
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="{% static 'smart-selects/admin/js/chainedfk.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'smart-selects/admin/js/chainedm2m.js' %}"></script>
</head>
```